# Does an ALB in public subnet can route traffic to Instance in Private subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a private subnet and a public subnet. Is it possible to route the traffic from public subnet ALB to Instance in the private subnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Yes, we can have Private EC2-Instances behind Public ALB*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what you describe is a very standard setup.